# Call dynamic method from another class in visual c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I try to call a method from another class in visual studio. I use a string from the array to the method call But the example uses simple string.

I read a lot of answers to such questions, but still do not know what went wrong. Nothing solves my problem.

**Part of form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Type type = Type.GetType("Database");
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        MethodInfo theMethod = type.GetMethod("MyMethod");
        theMethod.Invoke(instance, null);

    }
}
```

**Part of Database.cs**

```
public class Database
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test2");
    }
}
```

Script can not be executed because line `object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);` return error `System.ArgumentNullException`

Please help me fix this script.

P.S. sorry for my English -)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: The exception says the argument was null. Are you sure Type.GetType("Database") returns the type you want?

Comment: Try including the namespace in the `Type.GetType()` call (or the assembly qualified name if it's not in the same assembly).

Comment: I'm trying to run imacros scripts. I add a few classes and methods for each script. Then call them one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exception is resulted because of `type.GetType("Database")` returns `null`

You should pass fully qualified namespace in the parameter like following

```
type.GetType("namespace.Database");
```